# What is that syntactic construction in constraints definition?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

In grails it is possible to define constraints in domain definition. The constraints are look like some method calls inside code block.

Are they really method calls?

Can I put there some different method calls, like

`Math.sin(12)`

? I tried and got no error.

If they are function calls, then how to look the code of that function?

[image]

Is some method associated with any class field in Groovy, or these functions are added somehow in Grails only? How are they added?

I know I will see this later on familiarizing with grails, but I am nervous meeting mambo-yambo at the beginning! :)

Answer (score 1):

So, you have quite a few questions and I will do my best to answer them below.

First, constraints (what you are looking at here) are Grails only and are not a part of the Groovy language.

Secondly, constraints is a static closure, and not a method. The contents of the closure aren't methods either. The information within the closure is used by the constraints processing in Grails to apply the types of constraints to the various properties of your domain class.

Finally, if you wish to do your own validation (e.g. call your own methods) you can use the `validator` as noted in the [documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.x/ref/Constraints/validator.html).

I would also **highly recommend** you read the section in the documentation regarding [validation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.x/guide/validation.html). It has a lot of good information.

Comment: Isn't `void type(Map)` a method?

Comment: Yes, that is a valid method definition. However, if you dig into the constraints code you will see what is actually being done and those aren't methods in the way you think they would be.

Comment: Take a look at the source: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/tree/master/grails-validation/src/main/groovy/grails/validation